# How to create a main menu function that has goto statement in it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef en
#define en std::endl
#endif

using namespace std;

int login() {
    //Basic login program
    login:
    string correctPass = "Love";
    string attemptPass;
    cout << "Please insert password" << en;
    cin >> attemptPass;
    if (attemptPass == correctPass) {
        cout << "Access Granted" << en << en;
    } else {
        goto login;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // Everything below is main menu crap that I want to turn into a function that somehow allows goto statements
    login();
    mainMenu:
    cout << en << "MAIN MENU" << en << en << "Payroll" << en << "Employees" << en << en;
    string mainMenuOption;
    cin >> mainMenuOption;
    if (mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || "payroll") {
    goto payroll; }
    else if (mainMenuOption == "Employees" || "employees") {
    goto employees; }
    else {
    goto mainMenu; }


    payroll:
    cout << "Fish";
    return 0;

    employees:
    cout << "Eleven";
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want to turn the part of main that is the main menu into a function that somehow holds a goto phrase. How do I do this? I mean, I understand that goto and functions do not work well together, but is there another way that works at least close to the same?

Comment: Please don't use `goto` in code.  There may be cases where it is needed but this is not one of them.  Use loops and functions instead of `goto`.

Comment: Gotos that jump over non-trivial initializers or destructors are  recipe for disaster.

Comment: Change the definition of `en` to `#define en '\n'` unless you need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: These seems like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) why exactly do you want to use goto's?

Comment: Why use `goto` when you've got those bright if statements. Please put the payroll and employees stuff in the if braces. Use mainmenu function's return code to differentiate between possible outcomes.

Comment: "I understand that goto and functions do not work well together" Why?

Comment: Note: `mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || "payroll"` and `mainMenuOption == "Employees" || "employees"` will be always true in typical environments.

Comment: Another reason why you should never get into the habit of using `goto` -- whenever you have an issue with your code logic, and you want to get help from others, very few, if any would really want to look at code that is chock full of goto's.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is to write a `main_menu` function that gets the input and returns a value that indicates what was selected:

```
enum choice { payroll, employees, quit };

choice main_menu() {
    /* whatever */
    return users_choice;
}

int main() {
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        switch(main_menu()) {
            case payroll: do_payroll(); break;
            case employees: do_employees(); break;
            case quit: done = true; break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, to get rid of the `goto` in the `login` function (and, similarly, in the menu stuff), just use a loop:

```
void login() {
    string correctPass = "Love";
    string attemptPass;
    while (attemptPass != correctPass) {
        /* whatever */
    }
}
```

(I also changed the return type of `login()` to `void` because it doesn't currently return a meaningful value).

Comment: You might want to add another enumerator in `choice`, just in case the end user became smart enough to somehow enter a value other than the plausible ones, then loop back to `main_menu` in that case.

Comment: @AnirbanSarkar - the `main_menu` function should screen out inappropriate input and only return valid choices.